# MySQL split string, and check for equals

Tags: mysql

I'm making a kind of search engine where I use the MySQL statement `LIKE`.
Now, in my database each row has a column `keywords`, this column may be empty, or have a string with words separated by comma `example,string,in,column`.

Is it possible in any way to split this string when using a `WHERE` statement and check for `LIKE` on each word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with SQL.

A relational DB shouldn't contain fields with comma seperated strings. Each field should be atomic (only one value per field) according the "first normal form".

> values in the domains on which each relation is defined are required
>   to be atomic with respect to the DBMS

-> [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: Thanks, I have created a separate table for keywords and separate columns for each word now.

Comment: I have a new problem now that I changed it.
http://i.imgur.com/0WNcZQB.png
My MySQL query now looks like this, and only returns companies that has a row in keywords. I'm now trying to return rows that also does not have keywords in the keywords table. 

Is the query wrong?

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball your keyword table should only contain two collumns:   `companyID` and `key`. Then add a row for every company/key pair.